# .NET Maui Shell Flyout changes Color imediately after run

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

So, i'm pretty new to .NET Maui and I made a static Navigation (Sidebar), which is supposed to have some kind of purple background. When I run the project on my computer, the Nav-Bar on the side is purple for like 0.5 seconds and then switches to black. What did I do wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="JamIT.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JamIT"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Jam_It_.Views"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="#8319A8"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
    FlyoutWidth="300">
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Page2">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:View2}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem Title="Page 3">
    <ShellContent/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Is this a problem with MAUI or did I do something wrong? It worked in the beginning, and I can't remember changing something...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tested your sample and the Nav-Bar on the side remains purple which works well. Since you set the `Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"`, probably it's related with [[Windows] [Shell] Fix Flyout Background so it gets set in Locked behavior mode](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/6901) which has been merged.

I would suggest that you can upgrade your Visual Studio to the newest version which would resolve issue and mine is `Version 17.4.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a pretty solid work-around until this is fixed in the framework.

Leave your FlyoutBehavior to it's default setting (I styled my flyout background color in Styles.xaml):

```
<Shell x:Class="Osiris.Pages.AppShell"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Osiris.Behaviors"
       xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Osiris.Pages"
       xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Osiris.Models"
       Title="Osiris">
```

Then use this in your code behind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    this.FlyoutIsPresented = true;

    var animation = new Animation(x => { this.FlyoutWidth = x; }, 0, 300);

    animation.Commit(this, "OpenFlyout", length: 250, finished: (d, b) => this.FlyoutBehavior = FlyoutBehavior.Locked);
}
```

It will animate the flyout opening from the left, but does it so quickly you don't even notice it and there is no flickering with the other work-arounds I've seen.